# How to parse time saved in milli/micro seconds as integer in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm generating and storing time in milliseconds as follow :

```
(Time.now.to_f * 1000).to_i # => 1297073972278
```

How can I parse nicely this number to get the time object back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Time.at 1297073972278 / 1000
=> Mon Feb 07 11:19:32 +0100 2011
```